# I have a problem with laravel nova and showCreateRelationButton function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Im in laravel nova 3.6 version and I have a form with severals belongsTo fields. In 3.X version, a interesting function is available, "inline relations" allow to create a related resource using "showCreateRelationButton" but I have this code:

```
BelongsTo::make('Candidato')

            ->searchable()
            ->sortable()
            ->onlyOnForms()
            ->prepopulate()
            ->showCreateRelationButton(function (NovaRequest $request) {
                return true;
            }),
```

and no create resource link appears

[Belongsto Field create resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ6ZO.png)

I need help :(

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question.  Don't post images of code and errors. Do include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There's a known problem caused by composer **alexbowers/nova-prepopulate-searchable**. When you have that installed, the `showCreateRelationButton()` does not work.